# nvidia-smi causes terminal to stop showing user input

Tags: command-line, drivers, 18.04, nvidia, tty

I've installed NVIDIA drivers, and whenever I run `nvidia-smi` it causes my terminal to stop showing commands from user input. The system appears to be completely unresponsive, but if I switch between virtual terminals I can see all the commands I had entered along with their outputs.

I have tried using `reset` to reset the tty, but this doesn't fix the issue. What could be the cause, and how can I solve it?